# String pattern matching and insertion C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matching

I am trying to match and insert a patern in string.

Here in the `Good peo Good peo` and I am searching for `peo` and inserting `ple`.

But the Output is coming this:

```
Good people Good peo /n
Good peo Good people
```

I need to have output to be like

```
Good people Good people
```

**My code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int length(char s[])
{
    int len=0;
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

void concatenate(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i=length(s1);
    int j=length(s2);
    int count=0;
    while(count<=j)
    {
        s1[i]=s2[count];
        i++;
        count++;
    }
}

void substring(char s[], char dest[], int ip, int len)
{
    int i=ip;
    int count=0;
    while(count<len)
    {
        dest[count]=s[i];
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    dest[count]='\0';
}

void ins(char T[], int ip, char P[])
{
    char temp1[100];
    char temp2[100];
    substring(T, temp1, 0, ip);
    substring(T, temp2, ip, length(T)-ip);
    concatenate(temp1, P);
    concatenate(temp1, temp2);
    T=temp1;
    cout<<T<<endl;
}

void del(char T[], int ip, int L)
{
    char temp1[100];
    char temp2[100];
    substring(T, temp1, 0, ip);
    substring(T, temp2, ip+L, length(T)-ip-L);
    concatenate(temp1, temp2);
    T=temp1;
    cout<<T<<endl;
}

//where T is the original string and P is the pattern to be deleted whereever it appears in the original string.
void delpat(char T[], char P[])
{
    char temp[100];
    for(int i=0; i<=length(T); i++)
    {
        substring(T, temp, i, length(P));
        if(strcmp(temp, P)==0)
            del(T, i, length(P));
    }
}

//where T is the original string, Q is the pattern to be inserted and P is the pattern after which it is inserted.
void inspat(char T[], char P[], char S[])
{
    char temp[100];
    for(int i=0; i<=length(T); i++)
    {
        substring(T, temp, i, length(P));
        if(strcmp(temp, P)==0)
            ins(T, i+length(P), S);
    }
}

int main()
{ char a[100];
    char T[]="Good peo Good peo";
    char P[]="peo";
    char S[]="ple";
    inspat(T, P, S);
    gets(a);
}
```

Comment: c tag is inappropriate

Comment: When you write code, you should test new functions as you add them. If you had tested `ins` as soon as you wrote it, you would have noticed the problem then and there.

Comment: Why aren't you using strings? Homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The assignment in the function `ins()` doesn't change the value at the caller:

```
T=temp1;
cout<<T<<endl;
```

You would need to use `strcpy()` to the copy the `temp1` char array:

```
strcpy(T, temp1);
cout<<T<<endl;
```

2) Since you want to print the after inserting *all* occurrences, the above `cout` needs to go and you can print `T` either in `main()` or at the of `inspat()` (outside the `for` loop):

```
cout<<T<<endl;
```

3) Since the insertion happens in the original array, you need to ensure the array is big enough. Do something like in `main()`:

```
char T[256]="Good peo Good peo"; // 256 is some arbitrary size
```